# JdbcTemplate queryForList changing the database order

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

I'm using the `queryForList` method to fetch the data for the following sql.

```
String sql = "select * from my_table ORDER BY ? ? LIMIT ?, ?";
return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql,new Object[]{param1,param2,
                param3,param4});
```

I can see that the order is altered when the data is returned.To confirm, I tried using simple JDBC as follows

```
    try {
        Connection conn = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
        //Sample values param1 -> field1, param2 -> asc/desc, param3 -> 0, param4 -> 25
        String sql = "select * from my_table ORDER BY "+param1+" "+param2+" LIMIT "+param3+", "+param4;
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()){
        System.out.println("Name = "+rs.getString("field1")+" Type = "+rs.getString("field2"));
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Here, the print statement gives the output as desired. I want to use `queryForList` as it suits our data format requirements. How can I make sure that the order is maintained in `queryForList`?

Comment: queryForList preserves the order of the rows in the result set - the rows are mapped in the order they are returned from the database. you have ORDER BY clause, so the rows should be in this specified order

Comment: That's what I was expecting. But, I could see that there is also a problem reported [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/76907-jdbctemplate-query-sorted-result-set).

Comment: What I am saying is - the problem is not in queryForList - the source code is open, so you can see what result set extractor does (which is simply to iterate over the returned rows).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass the order by as parameters - `ORDER BY` ? ?. This will result in `ORDER BY "firstSort", "secondSort"`rather than `ORDER BY firstSort, secondSort`.